# is there a priority of mutex locking when pthread_cond_wait() receives a signal

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

when a thread A receives a `cond_signal` sent by another thread B via `pthread_cond_signal(&store.cond_stock)` then B executed `pthread_cond_wait(&store.cond_clients, &store.mutex_stock)` to unlock the mutex and wait that thread A send to it a signal :

```
pthread_cond_signal (& store.cond_clients);
pthread_mutex_unlock (& store.mutex_stock);
```

does thread A has the priority of locking the mutex, knowing that there is others threads (C, D, E, F etc...) that have already executed :

```
pthread_mutex_lock (& store.mutex_stock);
```

and waiting of the mutex to be unlocked.

Comment: There is no thread priority guarantees with regard to which thread receives the signal.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly (big if), the order of mutex-access is not dependent on whether the mutex was participating in a cv/mtx pairing.